# Configure temp directory to prevent making files executable

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Ubuntu 14.04: How I should set permissions on the temp directory so created files can't be made executable? Of course, any user should be free to create directories and files and delete his own ones.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71622/what-are-common-rights-for-tmp-i-unintentionnally-set-it-all-public-recursive it might help u

Comment: I don't see how this should help preventing the user from making files executable.

Answer (score 2):

The most effective option is to mount the /tmp dir with the option **noexec**.

From the **mount** man page

> **noexec** Do  not  permit  direct execution of any binaries on the mounted filesystem.
> (Until recently it was possible to run binaries anyway
> using a command like /lib/ld*.so /mnt/binary.  This trick fails since Linux 2.4.25 / 2.6.0.)

You can remount the /tmp partition with this option

```
# mount -o remount,noexec /tmp
```

Or put it in /etc/fstab to make it permanent

```
UUID=[...] /tmp                    ext4    defaults,noexec        1 2
```

To be precise, an executable file can continue to exist in /tmp, but the execution will result in a "permission denied"

Comment: This can be worked around by running (after making the file executable): sh /tmp/filename

Comment: remount only works if the device is not busy, correct?